# Facebook not picking video meta tags for embedded player

Tags: facebook-graph-api, video, flash, facebook-wall

Here are the tags on my page http://www.snagfilms.com/films/title/trembling_before_g_d

```
<link rel="media:image" href="http://ec.snagfilms.com/images/Broomfield/kurtandcourtney/kurtcourtney_600x337.jpg" />
<meta name="date" content="2010-02-01" />
<meta name="medium" content="video" />
<meta name="video_width" content="600" />
<meta name="video_height" content="337" />
<meta name="video_type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ec.snagfilms.com/images/Broomfield/kurtandcourtney/kurtcourtney_600x337.jpg" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video" />
<meta property="video:duration" content="5700" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Kurt and Courtney" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="600" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="337" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://player.snagfilms.com/SnagFilmsEmbedPlayer.swf?src=rtmp://snagfilms.com/guid:86e89160-a747-11e0-a92a-0026bb61d036&autoPlay=true"/>
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://player.snagfilms.com/SnagFilmsEmbedPlayer.swf?src=rtmp://snagfilms.com/guid:86e89160-a747-11e0-a92a-0026bb61d036&autoPlay=true"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Beginning as an observation of the music of Kurt Cobain and his Seattle/Portland contemporaries.  Watch free movies and documentaries at SnagFilms."/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.snagfilms.com/films/title/kurt_and_courtney" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="SnagFilms"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="214835748554764"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100001749790181"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me :)

Note: The first instance your website is scraped, the content is cached. So if you 'Liked' a page or sent an OG action at some point during testing, it's very likely that the content is cached. We re-scrape the content every 7 days if you don't force a re-scrape yourself.

To force a re-scrape you can use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.snagfilms.com%2Ffilms%2Ftitle%2Ftrembling_before_g_d (also helps checking your meta tags are correctly set).

If you want to do this programmatically, take a look at the Updating Objects section in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/ (bottom of the page)